# Application is not supported over the /common or /consumers endpoints error AD sign in

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I hope anyone is able to help me out with this problem

Im trying to get one of the code samples from the Microsoft Graph Api working with a company specific application. After I sign in at my tenant's sign in screen im getting redirected to the application with the following error.

> AADSTS90130: Application '{application id}'
>   (aad name) is not supported over the /common or /consumers
>   endpoints. Please use the /organizations or tenant-specific endpoint.

In my startup class i've got the following code:

```
    // The graphScopes are the Microsoft Graph permission scopes that are used by this sample: User.Read Mail.Send
    private static string appId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppId"];
    private static string appSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AppSecret"];
    private static string redirectUri = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:RedirectUri"];
    private static string graphScopes = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:GraphScopes"];

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {

                // The `Authority` represents the Microsoft v2.0 authentication and authorization service.
                // The `Scope` describes the permissions that your app will need. See https://azure.microsoft.com/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-scopes/                    
                ClientId = appId,
                Authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenantid}",
                PostLogoutRedirectUri = redirectUri,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                Scope = "openid email profile offline_access " + graphScopes,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    // In a real application you would use IssuerValidator for additional checks, 
                    // like making sure the user's organization has signed up for your app.
                    //     IssuerValidator = (issuer, token, tvp) =>
                    //     {
                    //         if (MyCustomTenantValidation(issuer)) 
                    //             return issuer;
                    //         else
                    //             throw new SecurityTokenInvalidIssuerException("Invalid issuer");
                    //     },
                },
                Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                {
                    AuthorizationCodeReceived = async (context) =>
                    {
                        var code = context.Code;
                        string signedInUserID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier).Value;

                        TokenCache userTokenCache = new SessionTokenCache(signedInUserID,
                            context.OwinContext.Environment["System.Web.HttpContextBase"] as HttpContextBase).GetMsalCacheInstance();
                        ConfidentialClientApplication cca = new ConfidentialClientApplication(
                            appId, 
                            redirectUri,
                            new ClientCredential(appSecret),
                            userTokenCache,
                            null);
                        string[] scopes = graphScopes.Split(new char[] { ' ' });

                        AuthenticationResult result = await cca.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCodeAsync(code, scopes);
                    },
                    AuthenticationFailed = (context) =>
                    {
                        context.HandleResponse();
                        context.Response.Redirect("/Error?message=" + context.Exception.Message);
                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
                }
            });
    }
}
```

In this code I have the tenant-specific id in the sign in url which works for another application with the same sign-in style.

I'm not sure what is wrong so i'm hoping there is someone who can help me out. I've looked at related questions on here but none seem related to this issue.

Comment: If the application is registered to use AADv2 end point the you should define the authority as `"https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0"` .

Comment: thanks for your reply @user1672994 . I have tried to use this endpoint but when I use this authority im getting the error: "invalid_request" with status code 302

Comment: Did you register you app thorugh the Azure portal or apps.dev.microsoft.com? Im trying to solve the same problem as well. I have this issue when I register the app through the portal.

Comment: @ozimax06 I have added multiple applications trough both the portal and apps.dev.microsoft.com but I get the same result

Comment: Mikey, here is the tutorial I followed and cloned the sample code from github(you will see the link on the video). You shouldnot receive any problem, I tested and verified that everything is working https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZHNPr7TRPU https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZHNPr7TRPU

Comment: @ozimax06 thanks for your reply. I will try this today

Comment: My goodness. I am seeing this same error as well. Is this an invalid error? I seem to be configuring this correctly as i am NOT using /common (i am specifying tenantid/v2.0.

Comment: I also get the same error. Cannot spot the answer for it in this thread yet..

Comment: @ImkeF I would double check if you are using the v1 endpoint. I thought I was using the correct endpoint aswell, but registering the application through https://apps.dev.microsoft.com solved the issue for me

Comment: Thanks @Mikey123, but unfortunately this didn't do the trick for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the v1 Endpoint to register your application via the Azure Portal and set Multi-tenant to `false`. This will restrict your application to only AAD users from the tenant at which it's registered.

If you want to accept any AAD user, you'll need to enable multiple tenants. This will allow a report AAD tenant to recognize your application and allow users to authenticate.

If you want to accept both AAD and MSA users, you'll need to register your application at https://apps.dev.microsoft.com. You'll also need to refactor your authentication code to use the v2 Endpoint.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want the application only accesable to the specific tenant. I've tried setting the application to multitenant anyway to test it but it still shows the same error. When I add the application through apps.dev.microsoft.com it still shows up in the azure portal.

Comment: A converged application registered on `apps.dev.microsoft.com` is inherently multi-tenant. In order to have this linked to a single tenant, you'll want to register the entire thing in Azure and turn off multi-tenancy for the app. Depending on the APIs you've selected, you may also need to get an Admin to consent to those permissions. You will also need to make sure your tenant `id` matches the tenant `id` you registered in.

Comment: This doesn't really explain the error message that the OP mentioned.

Comment: How do you mean? The code was sending a payload for the v2 Endpoint to the v1 Endpoint. These are different ID providers that require different payloads. Crossing the two will generate understandable incoherent errors (as I expect would sending a Facebook payload to Google). They're each using OAuth so they're similar enough to _almost_ work but they're not the same.